# Order List By Distinct And Object Property Larget value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need To arrange My List so I would Have Only Distinct Object Items with the Largest Object X Property. For example: i have this list of objects:

```
 MyList :

object[0] :
name: dani
x:3;

object[1] :
name:dani;
x:1;

object[2]:
name:joey;
x:5;

object[3]:
name:joey;
x:1;
```

I need to find distinct objects with the largest x values so i would get the new list with 2 objects like so:

```
 new List:

object[0] :name:dani;x:3

object[1] :name:joei;x:5
```

How can I find the new list? Lambda ex will be nice...

Answer (score 1):

```
myObjects.GroupBy(o => o.name).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.x).First())
```

Seeing as you don't provide details of which Linq provider your are using, this is the best general approach. You can speed things up in Linq2Objects using the MaxBy extension method in morelinq : http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

```
myObjects.GroupBy(o => o.name).Select(g => g.MaxBy(o => o.x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
mylist.GroupBy(o => o.name).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.x).First())
```